# What's that "for i, val : list: ..." syntax?

Tags: syntax

I remember that that syntax existed in some language! `for i, val : list {...}` would be like `{int i = 0; for val : list {...; i++;}}`, but which language was that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh hey, I forgot about this question!

Later I discovered that I had been remembering Python's

```
for i, v in enumerate(list):
    print('elem', v, 'is at idx', i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This exact syntax is unknown (and probably won't work in any language). So what I can offer would be

- Java Iterators:

  ```
  for(String i : new String[]{"one", "two"})
      print(i);
  ```
- [C foreach macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400951/does-c-have-a-foreach-loop-construct)

  ```
  for_each_item(i, processes) {
      i->wakeup();
  }
  ```
- JavaScript foreach:

  ```
  for each (var property in obj) {
      print(property);
  }
  ```