# Why use "(array) + count" in foreach macro?

Tags: c, macros

I get foreach macro from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400951/does-c-have-a-foreach-loop-construct)

```
#define foreach(item, array) \
    for(int keep = 1, \
            count = 0,\
            size = sizeof (array) / sizeof *(array); \
        keep && count != size; \
        keep = !keep, count++) \
      for(item = (array) + count; keep; keep = !keep)
```

I don't understand "(array) + count", it's equal "&array[count]", but why not use "array[count]" instead of "(array) + count"

Comment: Do you mean "why not use `array[count]`" (as written) or "why not use `@array[count]`" (as per your comment on what `(array) + count` is equal to)?

Comment: Suggest edit/compile/runit both ways, see if there is any difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but why not use "array[count]" instead of "(array) + count"

From [the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/400970/434551),

```
foreach(int *v, values) {
    printf("value: %d\n", *v);
}
```

In the macro, `item` is of type `int*` and
`array[count]` is of type `int`.

Hence you cannot use:

```
item = array[count];
```

But you can use

```
item = (array) + count;
```

since `(array) + count` evaluates to an `int*`.

Comment: you're right, use point is more saving memory, but if i change "int *v" to "int v" and "(array) + count" to "array[count", it's more convenient.

Comment: @nwaicaethi, you could do that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in `array+count` and `&array[count]` or `count+array`.

Its just these are both addresses so you cant assign them to an integer value as you did previously:

```
int item=array+count;
```

But to an integer pointer:

```
int* item=array+count; or int* item= &array[count];
```

Comment: @chux my mistake and thanx

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent, which one you use is purely up to semantic style of the programmer.

Arrays decay to pointers when you pass them to a function, pointers to the first array element to be exact. Thusly, you can use both.

Comment: NMDV There is no function call in the post so why "Arrays decay to pointers when you pass them to a function".