# Macro foreach loop in C

Tags: c, macros

I have this code

```
#define foreach(item, array) \
    for(int keep = 1, \
            count = 0,\
            size = sizeof (array) / sizeof *(array); \
        keep && count != size; \
        keep = !keep, count++) \
      for(item = (array) + count; keep; keep = !keep)

int main(void)
{
    int values[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    foreach(int *v, values)
        printf("value: %d\n", *v);

    return 0;   
}
```

Can someone explain how it works this macro? especially this allocation *keep = !keep* what is this for

Comment: Do you have an example of its use so we can get some context?

Comment: macros are a simple text replacement.  I suggest you perform this replacement (either by hand, or using a preprocessor program). If you still don't understand the code after preprocessing, most a new question.

Comment: in order to see what it does, why don't you just compile it and see what it prints?https://ideone.com/QKqUcm

Comment: @Anders Karlsson: I know what it does, I just want to understand the workings of code

Comment: `keep` is used as a logical value, `!keep` is the logical negation.

Comment: @Kevin Take a piece of paper and pencil and walk trough the code while writing down variables' values for each iteration.

Comment: Or you could step through the code in debugger. Pen and paper would of course work too. While you do this, think of all the people who will see this code after you, scratch their heads, and try to figure out what is going on here.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding it out by hand:

```
foreach(int *v, values)
    printf("value: %d\n", *v);
```

becomes

```
for (int keep = 1, count = 0,  size = sizeof values / sizeof *(values); keep && count != size; keep = !keep, count++)
  for (int *v = (values) + count; keep; keep = !keep)
    printf("value: %d\n", *v);
```

The outer loop iterates over the array.  The inner loop creates an item to which the current array element is assigned (`int *v`), and then the statements in the body of the `foreach` loop use that item (i.e., the body of the `foreach` loop becomes the body of the inner `for` loop).  The `keep` flag makes sure that the inner loop only executes 1 time.  Trace through the logic by hand for a few iterations and you should see the pattern.

Effectively, it's treating `v` as an *iterator* over the array `values`.  As such, it's fairly clever; you can use this macro to iterate over an array of any type, such as

```
double dval[N];
...
foreach( double *d, dval )
  do_something_with( *d );
```

But...

As written, this code does have some pitfalls.  It won't work with dynamically-allocated arrays:

```
int *vals = malloc( sizeof *vals * N );
...
foreach( int *v, vals ) // bzzzzt!
  printf( "%d\n", *v );
```

since `sizeof vals` only gives you the size of the pointer variable, not the size of the allocated buffer.  Similarly, it won't work on any array passed as a function parameter.

Be very suspicious of any macro that attempts to extend language syntax; it's *always* a hack, and almost always has a fatal weakness or two.

Answer (score 2):

The `keep` and `keep = !keep` is a trick, it can make `break` work in your `foreach`.

```
int *v;
foreach(v, values){
        printf("value: %d\n", *v);
        if(/*some condition*/){
            break;
        }
}
// After break, v can keep the status 
// just the same behaviour with for...break... in C language.
```

To get more details, please refer to [Does C have a "foreach" loop construct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400951/does-c-have-a-foreach-loop-construct)