# How to implement foreach loop on multidimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, macros

I have found this macro [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400951/does-c-have-a-foreach-loop-construct), where @Johannes Schaub used it to array. I tried to apply it to multidimensional array but I got warning:

**initialization from incompatible pointer type** [enabled by default]|

```
#define foreach(item, array) \
    for(int keep = 1, \
            count = 0,\
            size = sizeof (array) / sizeof *(array); \
        keep && count != size; \
        keep = !keep, count++) \
      for(item = (array) + count; keep; keep = !keep)

double DaysEarthSun[][10] = {
    //            0                                                         1                       2                       3                       4                       5                       6                       7                       8                       9
    //          JDTDB,            Calendar Date (TDB),                      X,                      Y,                      Z,                     VX,                     VY,                     VZ,                     LT,                     RG,                     RR,
    {2305447.500000000, /*"A.D. 1600-Jan-01 00:00:00.0000",*/ -2.568497981915648E-01,  9.438245451677045E-01,  6.410938668761658E-04, -1.684598702834566E-02, -4.667597482526307E-03, -4.906040833845624E-06,  5.649322014152373E-03,  9.781497849989120E-01, -8.026158042429985E-05},
    {2305448.500000000, /*"A.D. 1600-Jan-02 00:00:00.0000",*/ -2.736541829631095E-01,  9.390104932363517E-01,  6.360724040092633E-04, -1.676196451434489E-02, -4.960286450217222E-03, -5.142448255071298E-06,  5.648881285390255E-03,  9.780734751792867E-01, -7.236940265538736E-05}
};

void printSOE(){
    double distance, velocity, km, km_2, speed;
    FILE *f;
    foreach(int *soe,
                DaysEarthSun) {
        distance = sqrt( soe[1]*soe[1] + soe[2]*soe[2] + soe[3]*soe[3] ); // units: AU-D
        velocity = sqrt( soe[4]*soe[4] + soe[5]*soe[5] + soe[6]*soe[6] ); // units: AU-D
        km = (149597870.700*distance); // km/day
        speed = (149597870.700*velocity); // km/day
        km_2 = 25902068370*soe[7]; // E-S distance: light day to km
        printf("\n\n%f km , %f km/day\n", km, speed);
        printf("distance based on light: %f km/day\n\n", km_2);
        f = fopen("output.txt", "a");
        fprintf(f, "%f, %f,", km, speed );
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: `int *soe` is wrong

Comment: I tried `double * soe` too but the warning is the same

Comment: yes, neither of those is the correct type

Comment: How about just using a standard C `for` statement instead of using a macro that introduces a custom pseudo-keyword?  I don't see what you think you gain by your approach.

Comment: If you insist on using the `foreach` macro, however, then questions here about your code need to include its definition.  Linking to an external site for that is not sufficient.

Comment: I have forgot to paste the macro; code updated

Comment: Hiding two levels of loop inside a macro is plain nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two errors here.

The first is that you have a type mismatch.  You have `int *soe` but you are attempting to assign a `double []` (which decays to a `double *`) to it.  So change it to `double *soe`.

The second error is in the macro:

```
for(item = (array) + count; keep; keep = !keep)
```

It looks like you're attempting to assign an element of `array` to `item`, but that's not what's happening.  You do pointer addition on the array, but fail to dereference it.

Either add the dereference:

```
for(item = *((array) + count); keep; keep = !keep)
```

Or use the array element operator:

```
for(item = (array)[count]; keep; keep = !keep)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution looks simple but it was tricky, I would not find out without your help.

Comment: @user1141649 Something else I noticed: the inner loop isn't necessary since you're not looping through the second set of elements.  You could move the assignment of `item` into the upper loop.

Comment: OK, but I needed this code only for temporal purposes when I wanted to export some data. When the data are exported I will not use it anymore (I've finished). But I can use the foreach macro later.

Answer (score 0):

Your macro looks suspicious -- I'm having trouble analyzing why it does some of the things it does.  I *strongly* suggest that you abandon it and write your own iteration using a standard `for` construct.

Whether you continue to use the macro or not, however, you need to understand that C multidimensional arrays are arrays of arrays.  A pointer to one element of a multidimensional array is therefore a pointer to an array.  The type of such a pointer is different from the type of a pointer to the ultimate scalar type.

In particular, given

```
double DaysEarthSun[][10] = {
    // ...
};
```

, a pointer to an element of `DaysEarthSun` has type `double (*)[10]`.  You would declare a variable of that type like so:

```
double (*soe)[10];  // RIGHT: pointer to array of 10 doubles
```

If you want to iterate through your array via pointers to its elements, that's the type of the pointer you need to use.

Note also that it's quite a different thing from

```
double *soe;        // WRONG: pointer to (one) double
```

and from

```
double *soe[10];    // WRONG: Array of 10 pointers to (one) double
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an almost exact implementation of forEach: for(int i = 0; i < something; i++); as  forEach in this case would be c#'s forEach(int I in something){//code here}